# Mongodb: FInd one article for each author ID

Tags: mongodb

I have a user with an array of authors that he follow, like this:

```
"authors" : [
    ObjectId("5a66d368486631e55a4ed05c"), 
    ObjectId("5a6765f5486631e55a564ae2")
]
```

And I have articles with author ID, like this:

```
"authorId" : ObjectId("5a66d368486631e55a4ed05c"),
```

I want to get the last article for each author without making multiples calls to the database with a recursivity.

Some ideas?

PD: I'm using the mongodb driver, I don't want to use mongoose for this, thanks

Comment: how do you define that article is "last" ? Just by order or you have any timestamps in that collection ?

Comment: I have the createdAt, that is a timestamp property on the schema, I have others timestamp to.. like scrapedAt, createdAt, updatedAt, but sorting by createdAt i think it will be ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MongoDB v 3.6 you can use custom pipelines for [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/index.html#join-conditions-and-uncorrelated-sub-queries) operator. In your case you can use [$in](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/index.html) inside `$match` stage to get matching articles and then [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/index.html) those articles by `authorId` and take last one (using `$sort` and `$last` operators). You can add [$replaceRoot](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/index.html) to get initial shape from `articles` collection.

```
db.user.aggregate([
    {
        $match: { userId: "some user Id" } 
    },
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "articles",
            let: { authors: "$authors" },
            pipeline: [
                {
                    $match: {
                        $expr: {
                            $in: [ "$authorId",  "$$authors" ]
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    $sort: { createdAt: -1 }
                },
                {
                    $group: {
                        _id: "$authorId",
                        article: { $first: "$$ROOT" }
                    }
                },
                {
                    $replaceRoot: { newRoot: "$article" }
                }
            ],
            as: "articles"
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: This sounds great, but the think is, I want to the the articles from one user only, not for all users, I have a user loggedin on the platform, and he follow authors, and I want to get one single article for each author that he follow.

Comment: I did something like this: db.note.aggregate([
                {
                    $match: {"authorId":{$in: [ ObjectId("5ac78b66651389383e2fd688"), ObjectId("5ac78b7f651389383e2fd9f1")]}}
                },
                {
                    $sort: { createdAt: -1 }
                },
                {
                    $group: {
                        _id: "$authorId",
                        note: { $first: "$$ROOT" }
                    }
                },
                {
                    $replaceRoot: { newRoot: "$note" }
                }
]), what you think?

Comment: @cmarrero01 If you need one user then you simply need to add `$match` stage before `$lookup`, check my edited answer, I guess that's what you need

Comment: you are awesome. :)